# Windows 10: Legacy app having trouble opening its own files

Tags: windows-10

I'm running an older application -- just for the record, it's QuarkXPress 6 -- on Windows 10 (64-bit pro). Everything works fine, except that I can only open Quark project files from within the application, using File > Open.

If I try to double-click a Quark file in a File Explorer window, I get an "operation requires elevation" error. If I try to drag and drop a file from File Explorer to Quark, it doesn't work (there's no error message, though the cursor turns into a "no-entry" sign as soon as it's over the Quark window).

I've tried running Quark with and without compatibility mode, as an administrator and also started the program with elevated privileges via Task Scheduler. Nothing fixes the problem.

I don't think it's a matter of file rights or ownership, either.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Indeed, its a matter of it being a legacy app, and thus running in a virtual environment. File -> Open is one way to use this, the other is to upgrade to something that is not legacy.

Comment: Run the program as administrator and make sure the location with the files is accessible to the current user.

Comment: As noted in my original post, I am running the program as administrator and all files (the entire computer, for that matter) are accessible to the user.